# python - Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

This function always gives me the following errors when run:

CRITICAL >> Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
CRITICAL >> Exception for errors programming errors

I've spent hours looking at the code but cannot find the problem - What is wrong?

```
 #************ TestCase Table Insertion *********************
        def insertUpdateTestCase(prev_max_weeknumber):
                log.Log('insertUpdateTestCase START', 'info')
                insertUpdateTestCase_start_time = datetime.now()

                testcases = """INSERT INTO prtm_testcase (testplan_identifier, testcase_name, testcase_identifier, testcase_longidentifier, testcase_uri, globalconfiguration_identifier, weeknumber, localconfiguration_identifier)
                                                                VALUES
                                                                (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
                                                ON CONFLICT (testplan_identifier, testcase_identifier, globalconfiguration_identifier, localconfiguration_identifier, weeknumber)
                                                DO
                                                  UPDATE SET testcase_name = EXCLUDED.testcase_name,
                                                  testcase_longidentifier=EXCLUDED.testcase_longidentifier,
                                                  testcase_uri=EXCLUDED.testcase_uri,
                                                  weeknumber=EXCLUDED.weeknumber """

                # Define some variables for executing Select Query based on limits
                offset = 0
                per_query = 10000

                while True:
                        #execute query based on limits using projects
                        cursor_remets.execute("select tsdata.ts_moduleid, coalesce(tsdata_extended.ts_objecttext,'Unknown') as ts_objecttext, tsdata.ts_objectidentifier, SUBSTRING_INDEX(tsdata.ts_variant, ',', -1) as after_comma_value, tsdata.weeknumber,SUBSTRING_INDEX(tsdata.ts_variant, ',', -1) as project_id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(tsdata.ts_variant, ',', 1) as gc_id from tsdata left join tsdata_extended on tsdata_extended.ts_objectidentifier = tsdata.ts_objectidentifier and tsdata.ts_moduleid = tsdata_extended.ts_moduleid and tsdata.ts_variant = tsdata_extended.ts_variant where tsdata.weeknumber=%s OFFSET %s", (prev_max_weeknumber, per_query, offset))

                        rows = cursor_remets.fetchall()

                        if len(rows) > 0:
                                for row in rows:
                                        #print(row)
                                        testcond = (row[0] and row[1] and row[2] and row[4] and row[5] and row[6])
                                        #testcond = True
                                        if testcond:
                                                cursor_prtm.execute(testcases,(row[0],row[1].replace("\x00", "\uFFFD").replace('\\', '\\\\'),row[2],None,None,row[6],row[4],row[5]))
                                                conn_prtm.commit()
                                                DataMigration.validateInsertedRecord('insertUpdateTestCase', row)
                                        else:
                                                log.Log('In insertUpdateTestCase, row validation failed ' + str(row), 'info')
                        else:
                                break

                        #print(str(len(rows)) + ' rows written successfully to prtm_testcase')

                        offset += per_query

                log.Log('insertUpdateTestCase completed execution in ' + str(datetime.now()-insertUpdateTestCase_start_time), 'info')
```

Executed the SQL statement in the source database and rows are returned with no nulls or empty fields in the data.
Compared the list of fields against the defined statement and count the same number of parameters in both

Comment: `cursor_remets.execute()` takes two parameters but you pass three

Comment: You're missing `LIMIT %s` before `OFFSET %s`.

Comment: Is the intent to read rows once and update, or is the intent to do that in a loop until no rows are returned from the select?  Is there something removing rows from tsdata? If not, I'm not sure this ever returns

Comment: @Barmer  It's the little things. Thanks - I was going crazy.